# How create a Google Apps Script which update a google spreadsheet with an excell file adding non existenting rows in my spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet. I have to make it updated, and the file to update it is a excell file which have new entries (new rows) which I put manually in my spreadsheet. What is the best way to automatize this work, with a script which is capable of adding non existenting rows (in my excell file) to my google-spreadsheet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first step is to upload your Excel sheet to Google Drive and convert it to Google Docs format while doing so. 
Next, you can write a script to read your excel sheet (which is another Google spreadsheet now) and do the usual stuff like compare rows etc. 
Given your problem, you will mostly be using SpreadsheetApp, the documentation for which can be found at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app

I suggest that you take a look at the documentation, along with the other GAS tutorials and try writing code. If you encounter problems, feel fre to come back to SO with the specific problem you're facing